# Possible to run AVA tests inside a node server?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, ava

I want users to submit code and run tests against that code using AVA. The AVA CLI seems great. But this would be running in a hosted environment like Heroku and need to respond back to the POST request containing the code submission with the results of the unit tests.

When I try `var test = require('ava')` and then call the `test` function in a route, I get this message when starting the node server:

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
10:24:11 PM web.1 |  Test files must be run with the AVA CLI:
10:24:11 PM web.1 |      $ ava index.js
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
10:24:11 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible, it is thought to be used through the cli. Actually to me it does not make much sense for it be used as a required module in your code.

How did you plan to use it? If you just want to use the assertions you can use some assertion library like [chai](http://chaijs.com/), [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) or [power-assert](https://github.com/power-assert-js/power-assert).

If you want more information opening an issue in the AVA repo also could be an option.